# How can i stop my this future builder to stop reloading as i switch my botom navigation bar?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is that builder which i just want to load once.
I'm using a bottom navigation bar and this widget is in one of the tab; and as i switch between tabs this widget rebuilds. This widget doesn't rebuilds when i press on a grid tile and goes to the detail screen and come back to. It only rebuilds when i am switching between tabs.

```
class PostGridScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PostGridScreenState createState() => _PostGridScreenState();
}

class _PostGridScreenState extends State<PostGridScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) =>
        Provider.of<BaseProvider>(context, listen: false).getPosts());

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Claw Shop"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: Provider.of<BaseProvider>(context).getPosts(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: Text("Loading..."),
              );
            } else {
              return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {


                    return ItemGridTile();
                  });
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`. This will prevent the widget from being destroyed. You override the wantKeepAlive to choose when you want the widget to be destroyed. Below will always keep the widget alive. I have also moved the future to a class field so that it is not called in the build method (which can happen multiple times).

```
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

Note: you must call the super.build(context) with this mixin.

Edit: try making sure you are only building when connection state is done. You could also add other if else statements for other connection states.

```
class PostGridScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PostGridScreenState createState() => _PostGridScreenState();
}

class _PostGridScreenState extends State<PostGridScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  Future _getPosts;
  @override
  void initState() {
 
  _getPosts = Provider.of<BaseProvider>(context, listen: false).getPosts();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Claw Shop"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getPosts,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {


                    return ItemGridTile();
                  });
            } else {
                return Center(
                    child: Text("Loading..."),
              );
              
            }
          }),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Dan this was the first thing I tried but still the page is rebuilding.

Comment: I have just realized you are calling ` Provider.of<BaseProvider>(context).getPosts()` in the build method as well as initState. Try Storing the future in a class field so that getPosts() is only called once. I have edited my answer to show.

Comment: tried this too Dan, but it's saying:  Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<dynamic>-[String <'Page1'>]
lib\…\search\postgridscreen.dart:34

Comment: Dan the page doesn't rebuilds when I press on a grid tile and goto the detail page and come back. It rebuilds only when I am switching tabs between the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: Okay that error will be because when the future.connectionState == connectionState.none then you are trying to build with no data. Switch the if else statement round so that it only builds when connectionState == done. (I will edit my answer again) Then is there any need for the future duration 0 in init state? ... Storing the future as state while using autaticKeepAliveMixin should should it rebuilding. If it does not then could you post your bottom Tab/ wrapper widget?

Comment: Thank you very much Dan, this worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Dan. I was stuck on this error for so long and without your help i would've never done this.